# Centering does not appear to work in table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Hi I just can't get the text in row 3 to centre. Array package is loaded. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
\centering

\begin{tabular}{|c|m{5cm}|}
\hline
STATE & EVENT \\ 
\hline 
The vase was broken &  \\ 
\hline 
\multicolumn {2} {|c|} {The vase was \colorbox{red!50}{broken}}\\ 
\hline
& The vase was \colorbox{red!50}{broken} \newline by the dog \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Are you meaning *horizontally* or *vertically* centered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work, if you make the second column centered:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\centering

\begin{tabular}{|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}|}
\hline
STATE & EVENT \\ 
\hline 
The vase was broken &  \\ 
\hline 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{The vase was \colorbox{red!50}{broken}}\\ 
\hline
line & The vase was \colorbox{red!50}{broken} \linebreak by the dog \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**
Reposted the changed output

[image: Latex output]

Comment: the last cell has no correct horizontally centered text. Compare it with using `\linebreak` instead of `\newline`

Comment: Thank you, @Herbert `\linebreak` centers better. But why is the difference? I edited my answer

Comment: the first line in the last cell doesn't look centered; if you remove the space before `\linebreak` that should be adjusted.  (by the way, this doesn't happen with tex live 2010, and the code in `latex.ltx` looks stable, so i'm not sure what happened here.)

Comment: @Peter: You need different commands to end a line as you need different behaviours. E.g. `\\ ` in a center environment is actually a `\par` so replacing it by a `\newline` is wrong. The best imho is to use the intended end-of-line command. In your case either remove the `\arraybackslash`, use `\\ ` to end the center lines and `\tabularnewline` to end the tabular lines. Or store the "center meaning" of `\\ ` in a command before restoring the "tabular meaning": `{\centering\let\cnewline\\\arraybackslash} ` and then use this command.

Comment: @Peter; you should use package `ragged2e` and then only `\Centering`, then you can use `\newline` and also ``\\``. However, as Ulrike already wrote, `\tabularnewline` makes more sense

Comment: Thank you, @Ulrike and Herbert. Should I edit my answer?

Comment: Many thanks for your help. The code works great.